# How to sort an array I get using Wordpress function get_term?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, sorting

I am getting certain items using the get_term() function and displaying the result as a list.

It works perfectly as intended, but how do I sort the results alphabetically?

Code is as follows:

```
 <?php
        $terms = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'behandlungsfeld',
            'parent' => 0,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
         ));
         
         foreach ($terms as $term) {

            $the_term_children = get_terms(array(
                taxonomy' => 'behandlungsfeld',
                'child_of' => $term->term_id,
            ));

         echo '<li data-dropdown-text="' . $term->name . '">';
         echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($the_term_children as $term_child) {
                $term_child_fetched = get_term($term_child, 'behandlungsfeld');
                 echo '<li>' . $term_child_fetched->name . '</li>';
            }
         echo '</ul>';

         }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `orderby` arg like so:

```
get_terms(['orderby' => 'name']);
```